# Vim folding for PHP

Tags: php, vim, folding

Vim provides nice syntax folding for Ruby and C (well, that is what I've tried) out of the box, but what about PHP? It doesnt have this feature!
Am I missing something?

Comment: What makes you think folding doesn't work out of the box for PHP?  I don't use folding or PHP a lot (mostly Perl and Ruby), but it seems to work to me for PHP files.  What are you trying to fold?  Functions and conditionals (because those seem to work) or something else?

Answer (score 8):

Folding should work in just about any language that uses parens or brackets, so it should work in PHP.  I've added the following few lines as key shortcuts in my .vimrc so that I can automatically fold and unfold all my function definitions in a file quickly by typing comma f or F:

```
" Folding and unfolding
map ,f :set foldmethod=indent<cr>zM<cr>
map ,F :set foldmethod=manual<cr>zR<cr>
```

From there you can unfold, or refold levels using z and whatever fold command you like.  Good tutorial [here](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/114138).

Comment: link broken, any idea what it was?

Comment: An old xmarks entry says the title was "Linux.com :: Vim tips: Folding fun", which would suggest this as an updated link, and the Internet Archive confirms it: http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442438-vim-tips-folding-fun

Answer (score 3):

there is a plugin that should solve your problem

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1623

Comment: It doesn't fold newly written lines for me so I have to reenable it mannualy every time I have finished writing portion of code.